# How do you install hub (git wrapper) on Ubuntu with autocomplete and man documentation working?

Tags: software-installation, git, github

According to the [official docs](https://github.com/github/hub#standalone) you just download a pre-compiled binary but this would leave things like `man` documentation and autocompletion not working.

Comment: If you've answered your question, you might want to accept anyone of the answers.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecpick/+archive/ubuntu/hub) to install `hub` as a package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cpick/hub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hub
```

Comment: Do you know if this sets up autocompletion and the git alias?

Comment: @Bryce It looks like the latest package (2.2.9-0ubuntu0ppa1) contains a bash completion script, but no manpages or postinstall scripts.

Comment: ppa:cpick/hub has not been updated in years, and provides a very old version of hub

Comment: More up to date info on how to add a repo that contains hub can be found here: https://github.com/github/hub/issues/718

Answer (score 9):

## Updated answer

As PatKilg pointed out in the comment, the Hub maintainers now discourage using the snap.

## Original answer

*Hub* is available as a snap now. https://snapcraft.io/hub

You can install it with `sudo snap install --classic hub`.

Comment: Too bad Windows Subsystem for Linux does not support snap

Comment: Installing via snap is officially not recommended by the hub maintainers.  See README at https://github.com/github/hub

Answer (score 6):

### Install Hub

1. Download Hub from Github

   https://github.com/github/hub/releases
2. Extract it. I've extracted it to `Apps/` directory in my home and renamed it to `hub-linux`. So, in my setup, the complete path to the `bin` folder is `/home/anwar/Apps/hub-linux/bin`
3. Now open the `~/.bashrc` file and add the hub binary path to the `$PATH` environment variable. Adding a line like below will work.

```bash
    ### Adds Hub-linux
    export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Apps/hub-linux/bin/"
```

*Don't forget to to use actual path in your setup*

### Add the Bash Completion

To add bash completion, we need to tell bash to source the completion file came with hub-archive. The completion file is in the `etc` folder of the extracted hub folder. To do so,

Open the `.bashrc` and write there these lines

```bash
### Load Hub Linux bash completion
if [ -f $HOME/Apps/hub-linux/etc/hub.bash_completion.sh ] ; then
     . $HOME/Apps/hub-linux/etc/hub.bash_completion.sh
fi
```

*Don't forget to replace the exact path of `hub.bash_completion.sh` file according to your setup*

Now, You should be able to use hub bash completion

### Add Hub's manpage to `man` database

Hub's man page actually came with the archive. It's in the `share` folder. To add the manpage, we need to put it in the man page directory.

To do so, Open a terminal and cd to the extracted hub archive. Assuming your current directory is in the same directory where hub's `bin`, `share`, `README.md` reside, use this command to copy the manpage

```
sudo cp -r share/ /usr/
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/man/man1/hub.1
```

Now you can use hub's manual page using `man hub` command.

If you can't immediately use `man hub`, use `sudo updatedb` to refresh man db of the system.

Answer (score 3):

This script should do the job on Ubuntu 16.04 with zsh.

```sh
# Install binary and documentation
wget https://github.com/github/hub/releases/download/v2.2.9/hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9.tgz
tar zvxvf hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9.tgz
sudo ./hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9/install

# Setup autocomplete for zsh:
mkdir -p ~/.zsh/completions
mv ./hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9/etc/hub.zsh_completion ~/.zsh/completions/_hub
echo "fpath=(~/.zsh/completions $fpath)" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "autoload -U compinit && compinit" >> ~/.zshrc

# add alias
echo "eval "$(hub alias -s)"" >> ~/.zshrc

# Cleanup
rm -rf hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9
```

Alternatively for Ubuntu 16.04 with bash:

```sh
# Install binary and documentation
wget https://github.com/github/hub/releases/download/v2.2.9/hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9.tgz
tar zvxvf hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9.tgz
sudo ./hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9/install

# Setup autocomplete for bash:
mkdir -p ~/.bash/completions
mv ./hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9/etc/hub.bash_completion.sh ~/.bash/completions/_hub
echo "if [ -f ~/.bash/completions/_hub ]; then" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "    . ~/.bash/completions/_hub" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "fi" >> ~/.bashrc

# add alias
echo "eval "$(hub alias -s)"" >> ~/.bashrc

# Cleanup
rm -rf hub-linux-amd64-2.2.9
```

Test installation:

```
hub version
```

Comment: Your bash script contains the line `echo "eval "$(hub alias -s)"" >> ~/.zshrc`.  This looks like a zsh thing, not a bash thing?  (I'm a *nix newbie, so what do I know)

Comment: Thanks, the bash version works for me. One note, if one want to use other versions of hub, just replace 2.2.9 with 2.14.2 (or other version number) in the script.